# Count the values of a column based on the values of another column in R

Tags: r, group-by, summarize

Using the dataframe I want to create a new one which will contain Zip, Name and a column named Count which will include the count of Name per Zip.

```
Zip<-c("123245","12345","123245","123456","123456","12345")
Name<-c("Bob","Bob","Bob","Jack","Jack","Mary"),
df<-data.frame(Zip,Name,Name2)

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Zip) %>%
  mutate(Name = cumsum(Name))
```

expected

```
Zip Name Count
1 123245  Bob     2
2  12345  Bob     1
3  12345 Mary     1
4 123456 Jack     2
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output?  Not clear if you want an aggregate count, a running count or a unique count.

Comment: I added exp output

Comment: Why does `Bob` have count 2 in zip 123245 when they aren't sequential, and then another row with the same zip, and count 1? It's still hard to understand what you want.

Comment: there was typo i edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```r
Zip<-c("123245","12345","123245","123456","123456","12345")
Name<-c("Bob","Bob","Bob","Jack","Jack","Mary")
df<-data.frame(Zip,Name)

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df %>%
  group_by(Zip, Name) %>%
  summarise(Count = n())
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Zip'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#> # Groups:   Zip [3]
#>   Zip    Name  Count
#>   <chr>  <chr> <int>
#> 1 123245 Bob       2
#> 2 12345  Bob       1
#> 3 12345  Mary      1
#> 4 123456 Jack      2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

--

Quick speed benchmark:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(microbenchmark)

Zip<-c("123245","12345","123245","123456","123456","12345")
Name<-c("Bob","Bob","Bob","Jack","Jack","Mary")
df<-data.frame(Zip,Name)

JM <- function(df){
  df %>%
  group_by(Zip, Name) %>%
  summarise(Count = n())
}
JM(df)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Zip'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#> # Groups:   Zip [3]
#>   Zip    Name  Count
#>   <chr>  <chr> <int>
#> 1 123245 Bob       2
#> 2 12345  Bob       1
#> 3 12345  Mary      1
#> 4 123456 Jack      2

TarJae <- function(df){
  df %>% 
    count(Zip, Name, name= "Count")
}

TIC <- function(df){
  aggregate(cbind(Count = Zip) ~ Zip + Name, df, length)
}
TIC(df)
#>      Zip Name Count
#> 1 123245  Bob     2
#> 2  12345  Bob     1
#> 3 123456 Jack     2
#> 4  12345 Mary     1

res <- microbenchmark(JM(df), TIC(df), TarJae(df))
autoplot(res)
#> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: It is not the expected output?

Comment: It appears the expected output in question has a typo; if there is a typo, and the bottom row should be deleted, there are quite a few ways to solve the problem e.g. your `df %>% count(Zip, Name, name= "Count")` (clear and simple @TarJae, +1)

Comment: there was typo i edited

Answer (score 6):

We could use the `name` argument of `count`.

`count` essentially summarise `group_by` and `summarise`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  count(Zip, Name, name= "Count")
```

```
     Zip Name Count
1 123245  Bob     2
2  12345  Bob     1
3  12345 Mary     1
4 123456 Jack     2
```

Answer (score 4):

A base R option using `aggregte`

```
> aggregate(cbind(Count = Zip) ~ Zip + Name, df, length)
     Zip Name Count
1 123245  Bob     2
2  12345  Bob     1
3 123456 Jack     2
4  12345 Mary     1
```

Comment: Nice solution! It'll be a lot faster than the tidyverse approaches

Comment: @jared_mamrot Thanks. I didn't test the speed but hopt it is as your predicted :)

Comment: Did a quick speed test - significantly faster with the example dataset :)

Comment: @jared_mamrot Interesting benchmarking! Thanks for your effort.